# Pass vector<char>* to function getnameinfo

Tags: c++, vector, char, pchar

how it is possible to pass variable of type vector* into getnameinfo function of winsock2?

```
GetSocketIPAndPort( struct sockaddr* ss, vector<char>* pIP, uint16_t* nPort )
{
    if (status = getnameinfo((sockaddr*)sin,sizeof(sin),pIP,sizeof(*ptr),0,0,NI_NUMERICHOST))       
    {
        return status;      
    }
}
```

in face it is better to ask how it is possible to convert vector* to PCHAR?

Comment: This is C++ right? Then I'm tagging it [tag:c++].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `vector::data` member function, which returns a pointer to the underlying array:

```
GetSocketIPAndPort( struct sockaddr* ss, vector<char>* pIP, uint16_t* nPort )
{
    if (status = getnameinfo((sockaddr*)sin,sizeof(sin),pIP->data(),sizeof(*ptr),0,0,NI_NUMERICHOST))       
        return status;      
}
```

Comment: vector::data is very likely not available, it's a new function in C++11

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi define "very likely not available". It's been available in GCC for some time now, and MSVC 2010 implements it.

Comment: It's "not available enough" to justify your calling other people's C++03 answers "awfull" [sic] (to quote you).

Comment: @MahmoudAl-Qudsi okay, removed the comment. Anyway, why would you still use C++03 hacks to do what OP wanted to do, if the language already implements the exact solution to his problem?

Answer (score 2):

a `std::vector<char>` is safely convertible into a `char*` by writing `&my_vector[0]`   - e.g.

```
std::string fred("hello");
std::vector<char> meow(fred.begin(), fred.end());
meow.push_back('\0');
char* buffer = &meow[0];
std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
```

Comment: fontanini, vector::data is a C++11 feature.

Answer (score 1):

In STL it is guarantied that a vector layouts its items in consecutive memory, which you can access by taking the address of the first item, in case of `vector<char> ip` it is `&ip[0]`. The same way, for `vector<char> *pIp` it should be `&(*pIp)[0]`.

You can also refer the first item using `&pIp->operator[](0)`, but I wouldn't .. :-)

You can't, however, refer the first item using `pIp->begin()`, since this scheme is not guarantied to return a real address.